# How to run an R script from the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, r

I've spent over a week on this problem, been down so many rabbit holes, and I'm about to pull my hair out.

All I want to to is be able able to navigate to my folder in the terminal, run the command

`./program.R input.txt`

hit `Enter`, and go. But I keep getting all these error about libraries not loaded (`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib`) and needed to update the sudoer file and changing permissions and then the sudoer ID isn't right.

This should not be this difficult. What is going in here?

I'm also running Mac OS Big Sur 11.1, if that matters.

Comment: How did you install R?

Comment: Downloaded and ran the binary from CRAN

Comment: One of those on https://cran.r-project.org/ ? Isn't this a GUI version?